How can I create a shortcut in Total Commander to unpack the selected archive into the current directory?
Total Commander can unpack all kinds of archives. This is very convenient, but by default it unpacks to the target pane.
The "Unpack Specific Files..." dialog does allow one to specify the target location to any folder (e.g. the current directory):

When you pack files by pressing Alt+F5 you can simply delete path of your new archive, and leave only archive filename.
Example:
after pressing Alt+F5 on file/folder you have something like this
zip: "c:\path\archive.zip"
change it to
zip: "archive.zip"
this will create archive.zip in current folder.

However, this is an extra step I want to remove.
How can I create a keyboard shortcut (e.g. SHIFT+ALT+F9) that extracts the contents of an archive c:\Users\user\Downloads\<archive-name>.zip to the folder c:\Users\user\Downloads\<archive-name> without me having to set the target pane to the current directory, or fiddle with the target location?

Through the excellent help file and this Total Commander parameter cheatsheet I found the two parts I needed.
First part I found that when creating a shortcut for cm_UnpackFiles you can specify the target folder with the parameter /T, e.g. /T="." for the current directory.
Secondly, Total Commander offers the variable %O for the current filename without extension.
Putting those two together I could create a shortcut for the command cm_UnpackFiles with the parameters /T="./%O":

